# Adjust brightness and contrast on an Acer Aspire as5750?

Tags: 11.10, brightness, acer

I have an acer aspire as5750. With the intel hd 3000 graphics.

When i use the adjustment function keys the dial moves but it doesn't translate to the screen diming. Same with the dial in linux settings.

Also in colour settings it seems there is no colour file or icc profile available for this laptop. Do you think if i can get a working icc profile then it will fix this or not? I have found something that could work:Argyll but it looks complicated to use, has anyone here used it? Would it allow me to dim?

Or is there any other work around? I have searched lots but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have a 4830t and the screen looked awful.  I had to manual adjust the `rgb` gamma and the contrast.  Now it looks a lot better.

I create a simple script to adjust it at boot

```
#!/bin/bash
xgamma -rgamma .8  
xgamma -bgamma .6  
xgamma -ggamma .7  
xcalib -contrast .88  

exit 0
```

You can adjust the color and contrast to fit your taste.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is some article I have found on the subject:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/i-cant-adjust-screen-brightness-of-my-laptop-anymore

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_get_special_keys_to_work

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=131886

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_Keyboard_Keys

Those are not ubuntu specific and not a complete answer, but I hope that they can help you!

Please post your findings if any. I have exactly the same laptop and even though I do not have linux on it yet, I would like to know how to do that once I decide to make the move.

Cheers!